# Display elements in ruby array with every other element in all caps and all other elements in all lowercase

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to write a program that adds inputted words array. After the user completes entering the last element in the array, the words are then displayed, with every other word being displayed in ALL CAPITAL LETTERS. The other words, should be all lowercase letters. Is there a way to display the words alphabetically? This is what I have so far.

```
userWords = []

6.times do
  puts "Please enter a word:"
  userWords << gets.chomp
end

userWords.each do |word|
puts word
end
```

Comment: Sort them? Like with `.sort`? Then iterate and display as upper/lower using either the index's modulus, a flag, or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

#### Sorting your array

```
wordlist.sort_by{|word| word.downcase}
```

#### Getting every other element

```
wordlist.each_with_index {|val, index|
  if index.even?
    puts val.upcase
  else
    puts val.downcase
  end
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
words = %w{ It was the best of times, it was the worst of times }
  #=> ["It", "was", "the", "best", "of", "times,", "it", "was",
  #    "the", "worst", "of", "times"] 

enum = [:upcase, :downcase].cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [:upcase, :downcase]:cycle> 
words.sort_by(&:downcase).each { |w| puts w.send(enum.next) }
BEST
it
IT
of
OF
the
THE
times
TIMES,
was
WAS
worst
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution above should work, but in case it doesn't (which I doubt) you can also try this similar solution:

After grabbing user input like you did...

```
user_words.sort.each_with_index { |word, index| index.even? ? puts word.upcase : puts word.downcase }
```

Which does the same thing, meaning it starts with the first word uppercase, then lowercase alternating.

Now, if you actually wanted to array to be modified as you go and re-use it later, you could also do the following:

```
new_array = user_words.sort.map.with_index(0) do |word, index| 
  word.upcase if index.even?
  word.downcase if index.odd?
end

puts new_array
```

PS: quick note here: the convention in ruby is that for variables and methods you use underscore_case and for classes you use CamelCase